# Compare 2 columns of 2 different Excel files and put the value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 excel files with columns that have identical values and I need to put the coresponding values of another column in the other Excel file (refer to the image because it is more clear,).[image: An example of what I am trying to do]

You need a formula that finds the corresponding line in Excel file 2 and takes the value in the corresponding line and puts it in Excel file 1. I'm really bad at explaining things so just refer to the images.

I have try to find something on Internet, make google search, and I the solution wasn't working well or using an third-party application.

Comment: The parenthesis in column `A` of file 1 are part of the content of the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the use case for using `XLOOKUP` function, put in cell `A3` the following formula and extend it down:

```
=XLOOKUP(B3, $E$3:$E$9, $D$3:$D$9, "ERROR")
```

It searches for the code `B3` in `$E$3:$E$9` and returns the corresponding value from `$D$3:$D$9`. If the code `B3` doesn't not exist in the lookup table, then it returns `ERROR`.